# Android ImageView problem

Tags: android, imageview

I have and image (img1.png) in my drawable-hdpi folder, but im getting NullPointerException(?) when i use the following code. Did i miss something?

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("img1", "drawable", getPackageName());  
    imgView.setImageResource(id);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
```

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Which line is trigger the NPE?  Is it the getResources().... line or the imgView.setImageResource line?

Comment: I accidently put the findView after my code. My bad. Thanks for the help both of u

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize `imgView`?

```
imgView = new ImageView(this);
```

Even if you have done so, that's not the way to do it... it should be something like:

```
imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.img1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found a fix already, this may be to do with the support-screens tag.
In later versions of Android, if this is set to true, it will rescale your bitmaps for you and things change. I found that having:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

made getting a drawable image work as expected. (The image is returned in its native resolution).

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
```

This will make your image into a bitmap. Good luck!